# Can't Execute Query in MSSQL using JDBC in XPages

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, xpages

I am using a JDBC Microsoft SQL driver in an xpage to get data from MS SQL server
The driver is installed using an update site and it is loaded successfully into the OSGI

I have also added a sqlserver.jdbc containing credentials to the webcontent\webinf\jdbc folder in the application

When I try to access the sql tables using @JdbcDbColumn it is working fine

```
var con=@JdbcGetConnection("sqlserver");
@JdbcDbColumn(con,"PrTr","Descr")
```

But when I try to execute a query like this

```
var con=@JdbcGetConnection("sqlserver");
var query="SELECT * FROM PrTr";
var rs=@JdbcExecuteQuery(con,query);
....
```

I get a stack trace error (on line 3) with lots of error lines, the lines that stand out are these

> com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=4,
>   col=8: Error while executing function '@JdbcExecuteQuery'
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

I have also tried to connect a view panel to a JDBCQuery data source but then I only get a 500 error wihtout a stacktrace

The SQL server is not on the same windows server as the xpages

in the stacktrace/tracelog there was one line that looked like this

> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:362)

But not sure if it is an error or only informational and if it is related to the query. i.e if there is a security problem.

I need help to understand why I can do the @JDBCDbColumn but not the @JDBCExecuteQuery

btw I just checked the SQLLog and do not see any entries related to my queries

Here is the full stacktrace

> com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing
>   JavaScript computed expression
>       com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:132)
>       javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:159)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.convertValue(FacesUtil.java:1122)
>       com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.OutputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputTextRenderer.java:97)
>       com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeEnd(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:180)
>       javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:1005)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:858)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
>       com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
>       com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
>       com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)
>       com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)
>       com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
>       com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
>       com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
>       com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
>       com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
>   com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=3,
>   col=10: Error while executing function '@JdbcExecuteQuery'
>       com.ibm.xsp.extlib.javascript.JdbcFunctions$NotesFunction.call(JdbcFunctions.java:389)
>       com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
>       com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
>       com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTVariableDecl.interpret(ASTVariableDecl.java:82)
>       com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
>       com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
>       com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
>       com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
>       com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
>       java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:362)
>       com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
>       com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
>       com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
>       com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
>       com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:194)
>       com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78)
>       javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:159)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.convertValue(FacesUtil.java:1122)
>       com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.OutputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputTextRenderer.java:97)
>       com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeEnd(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:180)
>       javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:1005)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:858)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
>       com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
>       com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
>       com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)
>       com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)
>       com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
>       com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
>       com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
>       com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
>       com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 2
>       com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSValueVector.get(FBSValueVector.java:76)
>       com.ibm.xsp.extlib.javascript.JdbcFunctions$NotesFunction.call(JdbcFunctions.java:267)
>       com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
>       com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
>       com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTVariableDecl.interpret(ASTVariableDecl.java:82)
>       com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
>       com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
>       com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
>       com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
>       com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
>       java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:362)
>       com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
>       com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
>       com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
>       com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
>       com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:194)
>       com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78)
>       javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:159)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.convertValue(FacesUtil.java:1122)
>       com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.OutputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputTextRenderer.java:97)
>       com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeEnd(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:180)
>       javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:1005)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:858)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
>       com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
>       com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
>       com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
>       com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)
>       com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)
>       com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
>       com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
>       com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
>       com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
>       com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
>       com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
>       com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
>       com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)

Comment: Can you post more of the stacktraces?  and code?

Comment: I have added the stacktrace

Comment: Some more info can be found in the defect tab here http://extlib.openntf.org/?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/defects/159FE201622D941186257CA500580AD7

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem some time ago with column names being upper cased for a method in Extension Library code -> [How to get XPages and JSON to not put variable names in Uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716141/how-to-get-xpages-and-json-to-not-put-variable-names-in-uppercase)

I'm not sure if it's the same problem, but may be worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

To find out if it's a security issue you could allow all permissions to Java. Create a `java.pol` file in the `jvm/lib/ext/` folder, and add this:

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

(don't forget to restart the server when you're done)

I've done custom JDBC connections by including the correct driver Jar file to the database and I needed to do this to get it work.

Comment: thanks, I added the file but I am still getting the same error